# Magento 1.9 : Helper Data

Tags: magento-1.9, stripe

How to Fix this issue Magento 1

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cryozonic_Stripe_Helper_Data' not found in /home4/ghg3d1lj/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Comment: Can you share your helper code?

Answer (score 1):

Your helper should be like this:

> app/code/local/Cryozonic/Stripe/Helper/Data.php

```
?php
class Cryozonic_Stripe_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    public function myHelperWorks() {
        return "It works now !";
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Cryozonic/Stripe/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <global>
        ...
        <helpers>
            <Cryozonic_Stripe>
                <class>Cryozonic_Stripe_Helper</class>
            </Cryozonic_Stripe>
        </helpers>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

Then you call your helper function like this:

```
Mage::helper('Cryozonic_Stripe')->myHelperWorks();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cache` and if `Compilation` is enabled then you just need to disable it from

> Go to > Admin > System > Tools > Compilation

If you are not able to open admin then go to the following path and comment some lines which are mentioned below in `config.php`.

> Go to: Magento Root > includes > (open)config.php

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```